# How to add contacts from app to extension in Siri kit Payment

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I am developing a Siri based payment System app. I have implemented the Siri and its working fine. But I am adding contacts in static way. But my requirement is that, I will get the contact from my server than I have to save it in my extension. Please suggest me how to do this.
I am sharing some code snippet.
My AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Payment
import Intents

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Register names of contacts that may not be in the user's address book.
        let contactNames = Contact.sampleContacts.map { $0.formattedName }
        INVocabulary.shared().setVocabularyStrings(NSOrderedSet(array: contactNames), of: .contactName)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

My Contact Class inside payment Framework

```
 import Intents

public struct Contact {

    private static let nameFormatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()

    public let nameComponents: PersonNameComponents

    public let emailAddress: String

    public var formattedName: String {
        return Contact.nameFormatter.string(from: nameComponents)
    }

    public init(givenName: String?, familyName: String?, emailAddress: String) {
        var nameComponents = PersonNameComponents()
        nameComponents.givenName = givenName
        nameComponents.familyName = familyName

        self.nameComponents = nameComponents
        self.emailAddress = emailAddress
    }

}

public extension Contact {
    static let sampleContacts = [
        Contact(givenName: "Anne", familyName: "Johnson", emailAddress: "anne.johnson@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Maria", familyName: "Ruiz", emailAddress: "maria.ruiz@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen", emailAddress: "mei.chen@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar", emailAddress: "gita.kumar@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Bill", familyName: "James", emailAddress: "bill.james@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark", emailAddress: "tom.clark@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez", emailAddress: "juan.chavez@example.com"),
        Contact(givenName: "Ravi", familyName: "Patel", emailAddress: "ravi.patel@example.com"),
    ]
}
```

I am not able to set the contact from AppDelgate. Please suggest me .

Comment: What exactly is the error you are encountering, and what line is causing it?

Comment: Does the server exist already and does it have a working API? If so, can you post a sample response from the server?